# duplicating letters in string

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have a string in which I would like to repeat each letter thrice and generate the new string.

Below is my code but it has an output like:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000020DE9F7F8B8>
```

instead of returning me the new string.

```
word = 'hello'
str(x*3 for x in list(word))

'''
input: 'hello'
output: 'hhheeellllllooo'
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the duplicated letters using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), and you don't need `list(word)` to loop over a string, strings are already iterable:

```
word = 'hello'
print(''.join(x*3 for x in word))
```

Output:

```
hhheeellllllooo
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, how did you edit the code section of my post to make it more readable and in grey background?

Comment: @AmitAgarwal please see the [format help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) section

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a generator, this is a objects, that can be used in functions, when a iterator is expected.

You need to use `join` on this generator:

```
''.join(c*3 for c in word)
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as list-comprehensions are neat and easy to use, they don't fit to all cases. Most basically because they return... well, a list. You need a string, so it might not be the best approach. A simple loop will do the trick here without any conversions:

```py
word = "hello"
res = ""
for c in word:
    res += c * 3
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
hhheeellllllooo
```

Answer (score 0):

`str(x*3 for x in list(word))` returns the string representation of the generator expression `(x*3 for x in list(word))`, which is the output you see.

You can try this:

```
 ''.join(c for c in word for _ in range(3))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

<s>When you use parenthesis with comprehension you get a **generator**, if you use brackets you get a **list** that can be easily made into the desired string.</s>
You can use any iterable as long as the items in it are string, as I understand it.

The following code resolves this issue:

```
word = 'hello'
x = "".join([x*3 for x in list(word)])

print(x)
#Output: "hhheeellllllooo"
```

Comment: You can remove the `[]` and not generate a list, but use a generator expression instead, because join() can take a generator expression as argument.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, you shouldn't. List comprehensions are faster.

Comment: @Austin The idea that you can is important though. I made it sound as though you couldn't (because I didn't realize you could!).